# Какие программы по созданию UML могут генерировать Java код?

Tags: java, uml

Какие программы по созданию UML могут генерировать Java код?

Answer (score 3):

*Use Google, Luke.*

А так, например, [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/), [BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr/), [Violet](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php)... Кроссплатформенные.